# Eigenmodes in a Ring resonator made of 4 Mirrors

Tags: waves, reflection, cavity-qed

Let's assume a Ring Resonator, consisting of 4 mirrors that are 100% reflective, that are arranged in a square with lengh $L$.

What properties would the eigenmodes of the cavity have? Would it be that after one complete roundtrip, the wave is reproduced (that means, for plane waves, the eigenmode would be $e^{ikl}$, with $k 4*L = n 2 \pi $?

Or, since the 100 % reflectiong mirrors force the field to be zero on the plane, would the eigenmodes be standing waves with a knot at every mirror? That would mean, that the allowed values for the wavenumber $k$ would be given by $k L = n 2 \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

In a ring resonator, there is a one-directional beam making a closed circuit. Self consistency boundary conditions only arise when the beam meets itself after one complete circuit (as in the Bohr atom orbit). So your second paragraph:

> What properties would the eigenmodes of the cavity have? Would it be that after one complete roundtrip, the wave is reproduced (that means, for plane waves, the eigenmode would be $e^{i\,k\,\ell}$, with $k\times 4\times L=n\,2\,π$?

is a description of this situation.

Your third paragraph:

> Or, since the 100 % reflectiong mirrors force the field to be zero on the plane, would the eigenmodes be standing waves with a knot at every mirror? That would mean, that the allowed values for the wavenumber $k$ would be given by $k\,L=n\,2\,π$

describes four independent, standing wave linear cavities with *bidirectional*, *contrapropagating* standing waves. This is not a ring resonator.

Comment: But the condition for the mirrors to have a zero field on the mirror is still satisfied for each mirror?